# When I clicked on a subreport recieved exception: "The communication channel has not been created"

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a report, this report with several subreports, sometimes throws an error when loading "Could not load report", but however still loads the report. (not my current issue, just as some additional information)

I clicked on a subreport, and an exception was thrown "The communication channel has not been created."

Stacktrace is:

> CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.ReplaceConnection(Object
>   oldConnection, Object newConnection,
>   Object parameterFields, Object
>   crDBOptionUseDefault)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.ApplyLogOnInfo(TableLogOnInfo
>   logonInfo)

This is on my dev machine with local SQL Server running, everything is working fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

if you have taken Global Report document object and using same report document object to load report and set data source of main report as well as subreport on post back than crystal report generates "Communication Channel has not been created" error, i was facing same scenario and spent lot of time to solve this issue, finally i came up with following soultion..

Create new report document object each time u load ur report and set the data source, when u load report for the first time create a new report document object, also when u postback the page , generate a new report document object.  this solved my error hope it works for you too,,,,

let me explain by little Example

**CASE 1 :- with  Communication channel Error**

```
public partial class User_Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      loadReport();
    }

    private void loadReport()
    {
      rptDoc.Load("x.rpt");
      rptDoc.SetDataSource(datatable);

      rptDoc.Subreports["subreportX.rpt"].SetDataSource    (datatable1);

    }
}
```

-- this worked fine for the first time, but when i do post back and reload the report it gave me communication channel error...

**CASE 2 - No Communication Channel Error on post back**

```
public partial class User_Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    loadReport();
  }   

  private void loadReport()
  {
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    rptDoc.Load("x.rpt");
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(datatable);
    rptDoc.Subreports["subreportX.rpt"].SetDataSource     (datatable1);

   }

}
```

This works fine for me. hope it  works for u all.

Regards

Mahesh